# Las rutas de ExpressJS no cargan los archivos estáticos ¿Como puedo solucionarlo?

Tags: nodejs, express

Tengo la siguiente ruta

```
app.get('/asada/:id', getAsada);
```

#### views.js

```
getAsada: (req, res) => {
    var id = req.params.id;
    let query = "select A.nombre, Su.detalle ,S.texto from 
    subcomponentexasada S inner join Asada A on A.codigo=S.Asada_Codigo 
    inner join subcomponente Su on Su.ID=S.Subcomponente_ID where 
    S.Asada_Codigo ="+id+" and Año= 2018;";
    // execute query
    db.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err){
        res.render('pages/asada.ejs',{"rows":rows})}
    else{
        console.log('Error while performing Query.');
        res.render('pages/index.ejs', {"var1":"error","var2":[], 
         "error":"Usuario o contraseña invalidos"});
        }
    });
    }
```

pero cuando entro a `pages/asada.ejs` no se cargan los archivos estáticos como css e imagenes

cabe destacar que si quito asada de la ruta ejemplo

```
app.get('/:id', getAsada);
```

si funcionan los archivos estáticos

Comment: Ya logré arreglar el problema al usar `/asada/` los css estaban buscando la dirección `public/asada/css/estilos.css` cuando solo existe `public/css/estilos.css` existe alguna forma de no tener que crear una carpeta asada y que se utilicen los mismos css ya creados

Comment: Hola Joseph, favor añade el comentario como respuesta para cerrar el tema, me alegro que lo hayas podido solucionar.

Answer (score 0):

Ya logré arreglar el problema al usar /asada/ los css estaban buscando la dirección public/asada/css/estilos.css cuando solo existe public/css/estilos.css existe alguna forma de no tener que crear una carpeta asada y que se utilicen los mismos css ya creados